# URL to Complete list of native- & web apps for Ubuntu tablet version on BQ M10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, software-center, tablet, inkscape, scribus

Where van I find the complete list of native- and web apps yhat operational on Ubuntu tablet (BQ M10 tablet)?
I'm especially interested in professional graphical applications like Scribus, Inkscape, the Gimp, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can browse what is in the store using [uApp Explorer](https://uappexplorer.com/).

As far as "legacy" X11 desktop apps, the BQ M10 includes (as of OTA 10.1) a preview version of [libertine](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Libertine) and a container that includes LibreOffice, Gedit, Firefox, GIMP, and XChat-GNOME. There isn't a "supported" way to add your own X apps yet; I believe it is on the roadmap for OTA 11 at the end of May.